# 'Left middle finger' or 'Middle finger of left hand'?

Tags: adjective-phrases

If I write about a person's identification mark, which of the following two sentences is better?

*1. A black mole on the left middle finger.*

*2. A black mole on the middle finger of the left hand.*

Comment: I'm not sure this is about English as much as as which makes more sense.  What would you say in your own native language?  "Left middle finger"  kind of works, but "middle finger of the left hand" removes all ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The word left also means the hand that's on the left side of the body

So you can say:

.......on the left middle finger.

...... on the middle finger of the left or

...... on the middle finger of the left hand.

These uses are almost equally common.